# Does token-2022 allow selling fees instead of a basic transfer fee?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, spl-token-program, token-2022

I understand now that the token-2022 standard allows transfer fees but does this also allow a fee that only enforces itself when the coin is being sold just like on Ethereum.

Answer (score 1):

The transfer-fee extension in token-2022 works on *all* transfers, not just on "sales", since those are hard to define at the core protocol level.

If you want to enforce additional behavior during transfers, however, you can use the transfer-hook extension. That way, you can run any logic that you want.

Keep in mind that you *won't* be able to assess transfer fees in the same token in the transfer-hook case.

Docs on transfer fees at https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#transfer-fees and transfer hooks at https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#transfer-hook

Comment: is it possible for the solona smart contract to tell the difference between smart contract and a normal wallet so I can enforce a fee when the person sells into al liquidity pool just like how it works on ETH or is that just not possible at all

Comment: This is what chatgpt told  me. is it valid? It is possible for the token smart contract to tell the difference between a regular wallet and a smart contract wallet by using the account data and program ID, as I explained in my previous response. A regular wallet is an account that is controlled by a private key and has the system program as its program ID, while a smart contract wallet is an account that is controlled by a smart contract and has a different program ID.

Comment: It isn't correct in all cases, but yes, you can check and see if the wallet address is a program derived address by using the `Pubkey::is_on_curve` check https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/sdk/program/src/pubkey.rs#L631 just beware that it's a bit crude and will shut out legitimate use-cases